# Needed: introduction to FFT

Tags: fft

I am looking for a great introduction to FFTs for my job. I studied math, but never heard of FFT until I got this job. There is not a lot of documentation at my place of work and the articles I have found online have been somewhat confusing, even the wikipedia entry.

So I am looking for a recomendation for a higher level introduction to FFT. I would perfer free resorces over paid ones, but I can't be too picky here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be useful http://freevideolectures.com/Course/2252/The-Fourier-Transform-and-its-Applications lecture 22 is on FFTs. I haven't watched it myself so can't really say.

Comment: if your need is just the mathematical effect and how to use it, the FFT is "simply" a fast method to compute the DFT.  so all of the theorems you make use of are regarding the DFT.  didn't know whether this was where you're at or not.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following review paper very illuminating:

[Fast Fourier Transforms: A Tutorial Review and a State of the Art](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/498_13/signal_fft.pdf)
by P. Duhamel and M. Vetterli.

It covers a lot of things, from history to implementations.

Comment: Great source! +1

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: @DanielNetzer: fixed!

Answer (score 1):

i would recommed "signal processing for communications " by Martin Vetterli. It Deals with the fft and dft , analyses them and interprets the frequency domain plot of the signals. i think all your questions can be answered there!!

regards,
phanit tej